# mypy: Compare variable with generic type to a variable of any type

Tags: python, pytest, mypy

How can I compare the attribute with a generic type to a variable with a well-defined type?

I have a class called `ResultWrapper` that has attributes with a generic type.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional
from attr import dataclass

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")

@dataclass
class ResultWrapper(Generic[U, T]):
    eval: Optional[U] = None
    student: Optional[T] = None

def get_wrappers(evals: List[U], students: List[T]) -> List[ResultWrapper]:
    # Returns a list of wrappers.
    return [ResultWrapper(eval, student) for eval, student in zip(evals, students)]
```

In my test, I compare the wrapper objects with expected results:

```
from typing import List, Any

def compare_wrappers(wrappers: List[ResultWrapper], evals: List[Any], students: List[Any]):
    for wrapper, eval, student in zip(wrappers, evals, students):
        assert wrapper.eval == eval
        assert wrapper.student == student

actual = get_wrappers([1, 2], ["Bob", "Frank"])
compare_wrappers(actual, [1, 2], ["Bob", "Frank"])
```

This throws an error because the `eval` and `student` attributes are generic types that can't be compared with the integer, string lists that I pass.

```
    assert wrapper.eval == eval
E           AssertionError: assert ~U == 1
E            +  where ~U = ResultWrapper(eval=~U, student=~T).
```

How can I compare the attribute with a generic type to a variable with a well-defined type?

I don't want to cast the `eval` variable to an int in `compare_wrappers()` because `eval` could have any type. Is there any way to dynamically get the type of `eval` and cast it as that instead of hardcoding the type?

Comment: Why pytest worried about type hints? Is it some plugin?

Comment: yea I believe so :(

Comment: `U = TypeVar("T")` should be `T = TypeVar("T")`, no? I don't see any other error with mypy.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. If the code depends on any plugins for pytest or mypy, list them as well.

Comment: Python ``typing`` is primarily used for static verification – it does not commonly affect runtime behaviour, outside of some explicit tools such as ``functools.singledispatch``.  This suggests that the code somewhere explicitly (and erroneously) uses type variables directly. Be aware that the error message ``where ~U = ResultWrapper(eval=~U, student=~T).`` (does it include a trailing ``eval``?) suggests that ``wrapper`` is a *literal* ``ResultWrapper(U, T)``.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I notice you're using `eval` as a variable, which is confusing because it's also the name of a Python builtin. I'd pick a different name (or if you absolutely must, use `eval_` with a trailing underscore.

Comment: I don't want to put this as an answer, because I'm just not able to reproduce the issue on stock mypy and pylint so I don't know that it is the problem you're having. But to me, I'd be using the `TypeVar`s more liberally. I'd annotate the return from `get_wrappers` as `List[ResultWrapper[U, T]]` and the same for the inputs to `compare_wrappers`. That should allow everything to stay much better defined.